# Progressbar in Flask

Tags: javascript

I have a flask application, where the user can click on a button to retrieve a file from an S3 bucket. I have an object store class which downloads this file, it also uses a callback to update a class variable 'progressPercent'

```
class OSBucket(): 
...

 def download_callback(self, bytes_transferred):
        if self._size != 0:         
        
            self.downloaded += bytes_transferred
            self.progressPercent = int(self.downloaded / self._size * 100)
            print("{} %".format(self.progressPercent))        
         
 def download_my_file(self, fileName, filepath):
        self._size = self._s3.head_object(Bucket=self.BUCKET, Key=fileName)['ContentLength'] 
        
        try:
            self._s3.download_file(Bucket=self.BUCKET, Key= fileName, Filename = filepath, Callback=lambda bytes_transferred: self.download_callback(bytes_transferred))
        except ClientError as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return False
        return True
```

When the user clicks the butten a post request is done, details from the html page retrieved, and connection to the object store is established.

When the download starts, I want to be able to show a progress bar in my html page by reading the progressPercent variable from the object store. How can I do this?

Comment: The progress of a download is usually tracked on the client-side, using the XMLHttpRequest object's [progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event) event

Comment: @ChrisG I have seen a few tutorials that use xhr requests to do that. The problem I have is that I am not able to trigger the progress monitor event for xhr. Maybe because the python class is downloading the file via the boto3 library?

Comment: Is there a way to poll this python object for the progress from the client side? @ChrisG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do what I needed by using a polling approach. Once the button is clicked and the form is submitted, the javascript code detects this event and uses setsInterval to call the method make_request periodically.

It is make_request which performs a GET http request to the /track route and the value of the variable is retrieved and used as a percentage for the progress bar.

**HTML code**

```
<div id="Progress_Status">
  <div id="myprogressBar" class="myprogressBar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%; min-width: 2em;"> 0% </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript code**

```
function make_request(){
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "/track");
  request.send();
  request.onload = () => {
    //console.log(request);
    if(request.status==200){
      //console.log(JSON.parse(request.response));
      var percentage_complete = parseInt(request.response);
      $("#myprogressBar").attr('aria-valuenow', percentage_complete).css('width', percentage_complete+"%").text(percentage_complete + "%");
    } else{
      console.log(`error ${request.status} ${request.statusText}`)
    }
  }


}

$(document).on('submit','form#bucket-form',function(event){
   myVar =setInterval("make_request()",300)
  
});
```

**Python code**

```
@app.route("/track", methods=["GET"])
def track():
    return str(osbucketobj.getProgress())
```

where the osbucketobj is an instance of the class OSBucket (snippet of code shown on question), and the method getProgress just gets the most recent value provided by the callback in the class, as follows:

```
def getProgress(self):
        return self.progressPercent
```